# Gravity Forms Submit data to external database

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am having trouble with a form I created with gravityforms. This form's purpose is to grab the form's input, encrypt the password and write that data directly to a database. I have verified the database's username, password and IP.
The problem is that the form does submit, I can see the entry, but no data is written to the database. it just stucks with a loading circle next to the submit button.

Here is the code I use inside my functions.php file:

```
add_action("gform_after_submission_1", "create_account", 10, 2);
function create_account($entry, $form) {

    define('mySQL_hostname', '<ip>');  //database IP
    define('mySQL_database', '<database name>');  //database name
    define('mySQL_username', '<user>');  //database user
    define('mySQL_password', '<pass>');  //database password
    $db_link = mysql_pconnect( mySQL_hostname, mySQL_username, mySQL_password )
        or die( 'Error connecting to mysql<br><br>'.mysql_error() );

function l2j_encrypt($password) {
        return base64_encode(pack("H*", sha1(utf8_encode($password))));
    }

$str =  l2j_encrypt($entry["2"]);
$user = $entry["1"];
$currdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$email = $entry["3"];

    $db_select = mysql_select_db( mySQL_database, $db_link )
        or die( 'Error connecting to Database<br><br>'.mysql_error() );

    if ($user == '') { print'Incorrect UserID'; mysql_close(); }
        else {
    $db_add = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO `accounts` VALUES ('$user', '$str', '0', '0', '', '1', '$email', '$currate')" )
        or die( 'Error: '.mysql_error() );
}
mysql_close();

}
```

Also, what's the deal with the 10,2 parameters? I couldn't find anything that explains those...
Note that the above code, when in a separate php file, combined with an html form, work just fine....

Any help?

P.S: Can anyone help me build a function that submit this data to an external php file? In case I cannot make this work....

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with gravity for a bit, i managed to find a workaround.

```
add_action("gform_after_submission_6", "set_page_log", 10, 2);
function set_page_log($entry, $form){
function post_to_url($url, $data) {
$fields = '';
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
$fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
}
rtrim($fields, '&');
$post = curl_init();
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($post);
curl_close($post);
}
if($form["id"] == 6){//checking if the correct form is being used or not (optional)
$data = array(
"item1" =>     $entry["2"],
"item2" =>     $entry["5"],
"item3" =>         $entry["4"]
 );
post_to_url("http://www.example.com/post_data.php", $data);
//you can make changes to the data passed by gravity at the above url 
}
}
```

I have tested the above code with Gravity 1.6 and WP 3.5.1.

Comment: Tried, but did not work either... Using the same php functions on the same server as the target database seems to work however.... Any clue why this happens? MySQL allows remote connections and I even tried the root account...